# is it possible to have two or more ToMany relations pointing to the same object class?

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I am trying to establish a relation between objects like the one below. After adding different Order objects to mainCourses and dessert, when loading the Customer object, both mainCourses and dessert lists have the same values.

```
@Entity()
class Customer {

int id = 0;

@Backlink('customer')
final mainCourses = ToMany<Order>();

@Backlink('customer')
final dessert = ToMany<Order>();
}

@Entity()
class Order {
int id = 0;
final customer = ToOne<Customer>();
}
```

I expected that each ToMany relation could contain its own list of Order objects

Answer (score 0):

The `ToMany` relations are set up as `@Backlink` to the same `customer` `ToOne` relation in `Order`. [Backlink relations do not really exist](https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#one-to-many-1-n), they are based on another relation.

You could create another `ToOne` in `Order` just for desserts:

```
// In Customer
@Backlink('customerDessert')
final dessert = ToMany<Order>();

// In Order
final customerDessert = ToOne<Customer>();
```

Or create an actual `ToMany` relation for each:

```
// In Customer
final mainCourses = ToMany<Order>();
final dessert = ToMany<Order>();

// In Order remove the ToOne
```